# Is subring of a field always communtative.

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I just started on abstract algebra and I have a few amateur question which I hope to clarify.

So basically is subring $R$ of a field $F$ always communtative ?
($R$ contains $0$ and $1$)

If no, can I have a counter-example.

If yes, how do I go about proving it ?

Any help or insights is deeply appreciated.

Comment: What is the definiton os a field?

Comment: What can you say about a subring of a commutative ring?

Comment: Intuitively, I would expect the communtative property to be preserved. Since what-ever element in $R$ is in $F$, but is this a good enough argument ?

Comment: If F is commutative and R is a subring, then $\forall x, y \in R$ we have $x, y\in F $ so they commute. However, as @Mathchat said, what is the definiton of a field? Does it imply commutativity?

Comment: One of the field axioms is communtativity of multiplication. I see your point now. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I always thought that the french structure named "corps" would translate into "field", but actually "field" translates into "corps commutatif", as a field does require commutativity. Today I Learned.

Answer (score 1):

A subring of any commutative ring (in particular, of a field) is commutative.  Indeed, if $R$ is a commutative ring and $S\subseteq R$ is a subring, then multiplication of elements of $S$ is the same operation as their multiplication in $R$.  So if $x,y\in S$, then $xy=yx$ in $R$ since $R$ is commutative, and hence $xy=yx$ in $S$ as well.